# Is there a way to access a delta table old column name?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, delta-lake, dremio, data-lakehouse

I have a table with customer IDs, creditcard_number and creditcard_type (amex, mastercard, etc.)
I am trying to find a way to:

1. Modify the column name creditcard_type to type and creditcard_number to number by using a delta lake function
2. Have the old name of the column logged somewhere so that i can access it and use it to modify a .ttl-file (for a virtual knowledge graph mapping) where i search for the old name and replace it with the new column name.

I tried with change data feed (but it only tracks row-level changes)
I tried with column mapping (but column mapping doesn't modify the data files too). And if it doesn't modify the files too, i can't see them in Dremio (which i'm using as a federator to load the data further to Ontopic - the virtual knowledge graph tool).

How can i change the name of a column? Then access it's old name. And everything has to be done with Delta. Is Delta event capable of this? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can [rename columns starting with Delta Lake 1.2.0](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-batch.html#rename-columns), at least in Apache Spark (not sure about Dremio) - you need to enable column mapping by name (my table is called `test`):

```sql
ALTER TABLE test SET TBLPROPERTIES (
   'delta.columnMapping.mode' = 'name',
   'delta.minReaderVersion' = '2',
   'delta.minWriterVersion' = '5')
```

Then rename columns:

```sql
ALTER TABLE test rename column creditcard_type to type;
ALTER TABLE test rename column creditcard_number to number
```

And you can pull the old and new names from [Delta table history](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-utility.html#-delta-history) with something like this (pull history, leave only `RENAME COLUMN` operations and select old and new names from the `operationParameters` column):

```py
# fetch history for the table
tdf = spark.sql("describe history test") \
  .filter("operation='RENAME COLUMN'") \
  .selectExpr("operationParameters['oldColumnPath'] as old_name", 
              "operationParameters['newColumnPath'] as new_name")
# convert dataframe into a dict old_name -> new_name
names_mapping = dict([[r[0], r[1]] for r in tdf.collect()])
```

will give you:

```
>>> names_mapping
{'creditcard_number': 'number', 'creditcard_type': 'type'}
```